# Migrating from dual boot to triple boot

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, kali-linux, grub

In my current setup, I have

1. Crucial MX200 SSD - Kali linux installed with grub bootloader, set as primary boot drive
2. Corsair Neutron XT 960GB - Windows 7
3. Corsair Neutron XT 480GB - Shared data drive

Since Kali Linux is set to the primary boot drive, the Grub Bootloader allows me to choose whether to boot to Kali or Windows 7.

However, I have gotten an additional Intel 750 1.2TB PCIe NVME SSD and have installed Windows 10 on it. Right now, I can only boot to Windows 10 by going to UEFI and selecting to boot from the Intel SSD.

1. To add Windows 10 to Grub, I simply have to add a file in `/etc/grub.d/` and run `sudo update-grub`, am I correct?
2. After I migrate from Windows 7 to Windows 10, I would like to remove the Windows 7 entry from grub. However, the Windows 7 entry resides in `grub.conf` due to os-prober during the actual installation of Kali Linux itself, and the file says to not modify it, what is the proper way remove the entry in Kali Linux if I can't modify the `grub.conf`?

Comment: Please do not crosspost. If you think you posted to the wrong site than flag the question and ask to have it moved. ( http://superuser.com/questions/1047259/migrating-from-dual-boot-to-triple-boot )